# What's wrong with my async caller?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The parser is okay but when I put it into the context of asynctask it throws IOE exception. What should I do?

```
private class AsyncCaller extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<DummyContent.DummyItem>> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // This method will be running on UI thread
    }

    @Override
    protected List<DummyContent.DummyItem> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // This method will be running on background thread so don't update UI from here
        // Do your long running http tasks here and you can access the parent class' variable url over here
        List<DummyContent.DummyItem> list = new ArrayList<>();

        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(
                        DummyContent.UNAME, DummyContent.PASSWORD.toCharArray());
            }
        });

        try {
            DummyContentRegistry registry = new XMLDummyContentParser(DummyContent.url).parse();
            for (DummyContent.DummyItem t: registry.getTeachers()) {
                list.add(t);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail("Exception should not have been thrown");
        }

        return list;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<DummyContent.DummyItem> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // This method will be running on UI thread
        for (int i = 1; i <= DummyContent.COUNT; i++) {
            DummyContent.addItem(DummyContent.createDummyItem(i));
        }
        for (DummyContent.DummyItem t: result) {
            DummyContent.addItem(t);
        }
    }
}
```

meantime I've got stack trace:

```
08-07 21:34:43.264 26425-26775/ca.ubc.econ.montoya3.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
                                                                                    Process: ca.ubc.econ.montoya3.myapplication, PID: 26425
                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Exception should not have been thrown
                                                                                        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
                                                                                        at ca.ubc.econ.montoya3.myapplication.MainActivity$AsyncCaller.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:236)
                                                                                        at ca.ubc.econ.montoya3.myapplication.MainActivity$AsyncCaller.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:208)
                                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

What I want to do is to update a list fragment in tabbed activity? Without fail... I get

```
08-07 23:53:58.161 2567-3115/ca.ubc.econ.montoya3.myapplication W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Couldn't open https://oceanandcrow.ca/android/XML/Teachers
08-07 23:53:58.168 2567-3115/ca.ubc.econ.montoya3.myapplication W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "oceanandcrow.ca": No address associated with hostname
08-07 23:53:58.169 2567-3115/ca.ubc.econ.montoya3.myapplication W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
```

Comment: Remove the fail so we can see the original error.  This doesn't help us at all.

Comment: @GabeSechan updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It not like what i thought before ,seems like it connection problem ,verify your internet status, internet permissions

**Best practices :**

- Should implement Run-time permission request model for marshmallow and above (make sure to use a conditional check for Build version and use code accordingly )
- Implement connectivity checks to verify the internet connectivity (use NetworkInfo with ConnectivityManager)
- To avoid crash, Always use `Thread` for REST calls plus for long running tasks and use `AsynchTasks` for small tasks (downloading a song, image processing ,size around 5-10 MB) or use maturely developed libraries like Volley,Retrofit, (picasso,glide for images).